# how to create a xml structure programatically in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

i want to create a xml structure programatically in java

the structure is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <System token="com.test.dummy">
     <Parameter token="xyz">
        <Value>4</Value>
     </Parameter>
  </System>
```

i have to create a temporary file and then insert this data in the file.
I am new to this area, can someone help me.

Comment: You have 2 different operational models: DOM and SAX. Probably any of them will be good enough for you at your development point. Later, consider investigating on XSLT to execute transformations between XML docs. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/difference-between-dom-and-sax-parsers.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `DOMParser` best way to write xml in java

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b12024/oracle/xml/parser/v2/DOMParser.html

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteXMLFile {

public static void main(String argv[]) {

  try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    // staff elements
    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    // set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

    // shorten way
    // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

    // firstname elements
    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);

    // lastname elements
    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);

    // nickname elements
    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);

    // salary elements
    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
    staff.appendChild(salary);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

    // Output to console for testing
    // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("File saved!");

  } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}
```

see this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `StringBuilder`to form your xml struture. `StringBuilder` is light weight but does not know XML so doesn't validate structure at all.But its worth going for it because of its simplicity.

```
StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>");
   xmlBuilder.append("<System token=\"com.test.dummy\">");
   xmlBuilder.append("<Parameter token=\"xyz\">").append("<Value>4</Value>");
   xmlBuilder.append("</Parameter>");
   xmlBuilder.append("</System>");
   xmlBuilder.toString();
```

You can also make your elements accept dynamic values.
Make sure your xml document structure is correct

Comment: I guess that white spaces are not correct in this solution.

Comment: This wont even compile because. This is just invalid syntax because those inner " chars arent escaped.